# How to resolved the issue (qemu-system i386) Emulator android

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I want to test my application on **Android Emulator**, the message(qemu-system i386) appears and Emulator does not work

Comment: In AVD Manager change graphics from automatic to Software - GLES 2.0.

Comment: thanks, its Working